# How can I populate a join (many-to-many) table inside seeds.rb for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a model for team.rb and user.rb, which is a many to many relationship.  I have created the join table teams_users but I am not sure how to populate this table in my seeds.rb?

For example, I have :

```
user = User.create({ first_name: 'Kamil', last_name: 'Bo', email: 'bo@gmail.com'})
team = Team.create([{ name: 'Spot Forwards', num_of_games: 10, day_of_play: 4}])
```

But the following does not work???

```
TeamsUsers.create({ team_id: team.id, user_id: user.id })
```

I get a message :

```
uninitialized constant TeamsUsers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't optimized but

```
user.team_ids = user.team_ids < team.id
user.save
```

or if this is the first team

```
user.team_ids = [team.id]
user.save
```

ALso start using has_many :through.  then you will have a TeamUser model.  it's a life saver if the join table needs more attributes

Comment: Would I put a has_many :through on both the team and the user?

Comment: It's up to you. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a side to work from and then, as @drhenner suggests, use the `_ids` property to create the association. For example, working with the `User` model, create the teams first, then the users, assigning them to teams as you go:

```
teams = Team.create([
  { name: 'Team 1' },
  { name: 'Team 2' },
  { name: 'Team 3' },

  # etc.
])

User.create([
  { name: 'User 1', team_ids: [teams[0].id, teams[2].id] },
  { name: 'User 2', team_ids: [teams[1].id, teams[2].id] },
  { name: 'User 3', team_ids: [teams[0].id, teams[1].id] },

  # etc.
])
```

---

From comment above:

You can have multiple relationships configured on a `has_many :through` relationship. It's up to you which ones you want to implement. These are all the possibilities:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end
```

So, when dealing with the `Team` model, you can use: `team.memberships` and `team.users`;

when dealing with the `User` model, you can use: `user.memberships` and `user.teams`;

and if dealing with the join model, you can use: `membership.team` and `membership.user`.

---

You can omit the relationship references to the join model if you don't use it—especially if you're treating the relationship between `Team` and `User` like a standard `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end
```

This gives you `team.users` and `user.teams`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails, say you have tables `foos` and `bars` in a many-to-many relationship using table `foos_bars`, you can seed their associations like this:

```
bar1 = Bar.find(1)
bar2 = Bar.find(2)

foo1 = Foo.find(1) # for example
foo1.bars << bar1
foo1.bars << bar2
foo1.save
```

This will update the joins table `foos_bars` with associations `<foo_id:1, bar_id:1>`, `<foo_id:1, bar_id:2>`

Hope this helps.